# How to add a global svn credential in jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins, credentials

I'm beginner in Jenkins. And I want to add maven jobs in Jenkins without having to add new svn credentials for each job.

Our company decided to build our products only using Jenkins Server that checks out projects from svn server. Because of security issues, job creation and build action should be done by an admin user that does not have any access to SVN repositories and only can get the output war/jar files from Jenkins that are deployed to Artifactory server. I also defined a global svn user that has read access to all our svn repos. Now, each time the admin user create a new Jenkins job, I have to get there and add the this svn user credential for the new repo url.

Is there any solution in Jenkins to add a global svn credential for all repositories, so that I don't have to specify that for every job?